# I m looking for best practice related to configure content delivery server and content authoring server in production Env

Tags: deployment, scaling

I looked into sitecore documentation below.
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_a_content_delivery_server
Is this list comprehensive or we have anything more to take care. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to server configuration, there is also the equivalent documentation for [configuring a content management server](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_a_content_management_server).  Make sure you are reading the documentation relevant to the version of Sitecore you are using the version selector dropdown in the right hand column.

You should also look into the Security Hardening Guide (on https://sdn.sitecore.net, you will need to log in) and the new [Security Hardening section](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/security_hardening) for your production environments (and really, for your other environments as well).

If you have any modules (eg. EXM / WFFM / FXM) you should read the module-specific documentation as they sometimes have different configuration necessary for CM and CD servers.

In regards to architecture options there are a number of other pages (for example the [architecture overview](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/platform/architecture_overview)) but it sounds like you're after more specific configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the link-heavy answer, but there's a lot of different options we have:

Looking at the Sitecore configuration, you can find the details for Content Management server [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_a_content_management_server), and the Content Delivery server [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_a_content_delivery_server).

Find the details for configuring a reporting server [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_a_reporting_service_server), and the details on the processing server configuration can be [found here](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_a_processing_server).

[Find here](https://doc.sitecore.net//~/media/F50C507B9BC04FEB9C9D933433A9C3C3.ashx?la=en) a downloadable Excel file showing which .config files should be enabled and disabled on Content Management, Content Deliver, Processing or Reporting server.

However, keep in mind this is only Sitecore 'role' configurations, not touching on hardware, infrastructure and the like, or even things like Security (see Jason's answer), caching or [xDB configuration](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb).